# QuickMapServices plugin generates distorted basemap

Tags: qgis, quickmapservices, nextgis

Why do the QuickMapServices plugin generates distorted basemap?
I tried different sources but the result was odd every time.
I'm using QGIS 2.16.2 and QuickMapServices 0.17.8.

[image: Yandex Map]

[image: OSM Mapnik]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your QGIS default SRS set to 4326 (WGS84). Change SRS to 3857 (OSM) or 3395 (Yandex). Select right SRS via globe icon at right bottom corner of QGIS (don't forget enable on the fly reprojection).

[image]